# 'includes' does not exists on type 'string[]' in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecma

From this question and the accepted answer, I know that there is an methode to [check if an array includes an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript) by using this line of code:

> ```
> > ['joe', 'jane', 'mary'].includes('jane');
> true
> ```

However if I use the same code in **TypeScript** I've got this error:

> Property `includes` does not exist on type `string[]`.

1. Why gives the compiler this error? I'm expecting that everything that is available in JS, is available in TS.
2. How could I solve this error without changing the code? It must be working on ES5.

Comment: @Baboo_: It's not a duplicate because my question goes about **TypeScript** and not about JavaScript like the link you provided!

Comment: I missed copied, the link you provided is the one I wanted to provide ;)

Answer (score 6):

Includes is defined in the `lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts`  since it is part of the `es2016` standard. You can include this lib in your `tsconfig` but you have to provide your own polyfil for the method:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "scripthost",
            "es5",
            "es2016.array.include"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can also provide the polyfill by assigning `Array.prototype.include` if your runtime does not provide this method on array (you can get a polyfill from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for example)